# How to get the name of a private field of a child class from the super class using reflection or libraries?

Tags: java, selenium, variables, reflection, selenium-extent-report

Let's say I have this code structure:

```
public abstract class A {
 // members
 ...
 
 // constructor
 ...
 
 // methods
 protected void enterValue(By locator, String value) {
  ...
  System.out.println("entered " + value + " into the " + locator...);
 }
}

public class B extends A {
 // members
 private final By SEARCH_FIELD = By.id("search");
 // ... other FIELD members
 
 // constructor
 ...

 // methods
 public void searchProduct(String product) {
  enterValue(SEARCH_FIELD, product);
  ...
 }
}
```

The enterValue(By, String) method should print for example: "entered Talent into the SEARCH_FIELD".
Also, I can have other classes of the same structure as class B that can call the class A method so I don't know the child's class name and which field it would be in advance.
Is this something I can achieve with Reflection in Java or with some libraries?
My goal is to log every action with meaningful names into my ExtentReports.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Is it to have code that "automatically" find the locator so you don't have to pass it to enterValue() ?

Comment: I'm trying to find the name of the private field that was used to call the enterValue method, so if I write this enterValue(FIELD, "text"), it would prints "FIELD" and not the parameter name which is "locator".

Comment: As far as I know, that is not really possible. What you could do, I suppose, is to loop through all fields in the class and find one that matches the type and value. I would seek another solution though. For example, an abstract method getLocatorName() that each client must implement that returns a String with the name you want printed which is called in place of "locator....".

Comment: getDeclaredField... then setAccessible(true)...  but if you come to this there is surely something wrong with your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

`getDeclaredFields()` of `Class` gives all the declared fields in the class both public and private. It won't return inherited field .You can use Modifier to check if it is private or not.

```
List<Field> privateFieldList = new ArrayList<>();
Field[] Fields = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : Fields) {
    if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
        privateFieldList.add(field);
    }
}
```

Use Field.getType() to check the type

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, I'd seek a different solution.

Typically, for similar problems, I use an abstract method:

```
public abstract class A {

    protected abstract String getLocatorName();

    protected void enterValue(String value) {
        System.out.println("entered " + value + " into the " + getLocatorName() + "...");
    }
}
```

Implement it in the child class:

```
public class B extends A {

    private static final String LOCATOR_NAME = "SEARCH_FIELD";
    private final By searchField = By.id("search");

    public void searchProduct(String product) {
        enterValue(product);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getLocatorName() {
        return LOCATOR_NAME;
    }
}
```